# Active Directory authentication via spring security returns bad credential for valid users caused by LDAP: error code 49

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a spring boot maven project to authenticate users having username and password. The microservice needs to return true/false if user is authenticated.

The SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.app.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    private String url = "ldaps://org.abc.in:3387";
    private String domain = "org.abc.in";
    private String userDNPattern = "CN=pan,OU=Users,OU=UCV,DC=org,DC=abc,DC=in";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "logout").permitAll();

    }


     @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {              
         auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());

        }

     @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
         return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
        }

     @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url);
            adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
            //adProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new NullAuthoritiesMapper());
            return adProvider;
        }

}
```

I am calling the following method by passing username and password

```
public Authentication signin(String username, String password) throws Exception{
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("pan@abc.in", "password");
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(auth); // this line gives Bad Credential error
    }
```

I am getting the following error when calling method authenticationManager.authenticate(auth)

```
ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:308)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

I went through the following links:
[javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689964/javax-naming-authenticationexception-ldap-error-code-49-invalid-credentials)

[Active Directory Authentication using Spring Security 3.2, Spring Ldap 2.0 and JavaConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295616/active-directory-authentication-using-spring-security-3-2-spring-ldap-2-0-and-j)

[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411665/ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecurityc)

Based on above links I have tried setAuthoritiesMapper and passed NullAuthoritiesMapper as I don't have any authorities to map.

```
adProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new NullAuthoritiesMapper());
```

I tried to make changes to `userDNPattern = "CN=pan,OU=Users,OU=UCV,DC=org,DC=abc,DC=in";`but it didn't work. CN= pan is my username

I am able to access the Apache Active Directory with above url, domain and userDnPattern and password. Do I need to encode the password?

Comment: is this your full username including the domain "pan@abc.in"?

Comment: @slimane username is pan   and rest is domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your domain is "org.abc.in".
change "pan@abc.in" to "pan", ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider will automatically add your domain to it as you already specified it during it's creation ("org.abc.in").

Comment: My domain name was set incorrectly. It has to be abc.in and not org.abc.in

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the only problem, but this is certainly part of it:

```
adProvider.setSearchFilter(userDNPattern);
```

That method takes the LDAP query to find the user, not a DN. The [documentation for `setSearchFilter()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html#setSearchFilter-java.lang.String-) says that the default is this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))
```

That will take the username you give it, and find the user with that `userPrincipalName` ("username@domain.com" format).

If that's what you want, then you don't need to call `setSearchFilter()` at all.

If you want users to be able to login using just the username (`sAMAccountName`), then you can use this:

```
adProvider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))");
```

*Update:* I think you have a couple other problems too:

```
private String url = "ldaps://org.abc.in:3387";
private String domain = "org.abc.in";
```

First, `ldaps://` isn't actually valid. Just use `ldap://`. If the specified port uses SSL, then it will do the SSL handshake.

Also, you're setting the domain to `org.abc.in`, but when you're logging in, you're using `@abc.in`. The `domain` you specify is appended to the username you specify for login, so it's trying to log you in with `pan@abc.in@org.abc.in`, which of course won't work. You are better off just setting the `domain` to `null` so it doesn't try to append anything later. But that would mean your users would need to login with the `username@abc.in` format.

Comment: I have removed adProvider.setSearchFilter(userDNPattern); now as it doesn't make any changes in the output. authenticationManager.authenticate(auth) still returns - Bad credentials

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information. But there is also this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591738/1202807

Comment: There is no issue in SSL handshake. private String url = "ldaps://org.abc.in:3387"; works as well. The handshake is happening as expected. My domain was not set properly as explained by you. Instead of org.abc.in I set it to abc.in and passed just username pan : Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("pan", "password"); This works as expected.